# Error while uploading a facebook tab page to facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-tabs

IM trying to upload my facebook tab page (**sindri55.com/rakang**) to facebook. The website works fine on sindri55.com/rakang but gives me a load of errors on facebook.com.

I will reather let you check console log on the website to check the html code.. since its to big to load here.

**Facebook test page is: [https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rakang/1380005998992035?sk=app_190322544333196#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rakang/1380005998992035?sk=app_190322544333196#_=_)**

```
Navigated to https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rakang/1380005998992035?sk=app_190322544333196

6sdk.js:64 Received message of type object from https://raw.statichtmlapp.com,  expected a string

inject.js:1 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.

inject.js:1 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.

inject.js:1 forwarding exception 0 frameElement

(index):214 gooo


sdk.js:64 Received message of type object from 

https://statichtmlproxy.thunderpenny.com, expected a string

2sdk.js:64 Received message of type object from https://raw.statichtmlapp.com, expected a string

6Dg4oLkBbYq.js?version=41:41 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://apps.tweecode.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://statichtmlproxy.thunderpenny.com').

sdk.js:64 Received message of type object from https://raw.statichtmlapp.com, expected a string

ping?

client_id=747307895388602&domain=statichtmlproxy.thunderpenny.com&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%…:1 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
36sdk.js:64 Received message of type object from https://raw.statichtmlapp.com, expected a string
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing, "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains" means that you need to add your Page Tab Name and a Secure Page Tab URL to your app settings(under Settings > Basic).

[image: Page Tab settings]

Here's the [doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs) explaining how to do it.

Once you do, this warning should go away, if it doesn't I suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes I think its becouse my website is using http and not SSL.. its in the process right now, and thanks!